Difficulty calculating late, on_time, and early totals in flights dataset with summarize()
I want to find the total number of flights that departed late, on_time, and early in the nycflights13 "flights" database, but my code is only outputting "NA".
I tried to use the summarize R function to create these total sums, and the tibble sets up as expected, but the values are all set to NA. I believe the logic of my code should hold, so something about the formatting of my code is likely causing the NA results to show up.
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)

flights |> 
  summarize(
    late = sum(dep_delay > 0),
    on_time = sum(dep_delay == 0),
    early = sum(dep_delay < 0)
  )

#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>    late on_time early
#>   <int>   <int> <int>
#> 1    NA      NA    NA

Created on 2024-10-27 with reprex v2.1.1
